# Openldap "ldapmodify" command fails to run

Tags: openldap

I'm attempting to update a config parameter within my openldap server by using ldapmodify, but I'm getting the following error:

```
# ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f tls.ldif
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "cn=config"
ldap_modify: Confidentiality required (13)
        additional info: stronger confidentiality required
```

Other answers to other questions lead to not having a strong enough SSF value, which is currently set to 70, but my question here is - is this a catch-22 scenario?  I need to use the same ldapmodify command to update the SSF value, do I not?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to make sure you're not setting yourself up for additional problems, what are the contents of tls.ldif and what SSF-related or "require TLS"-related settings did you use so far?

Answer (score 1):

Use `slapadd` or `slapmodify` to make changes directly to a database, bypassing the LDAP server.

```
sudo -u ldap slapmodify -n 0 -w < tls.ldif
systemctl restart slapd
```

Or, if your backend configuration for cn=config has a "root DN" defined and you know its password, make ldapmodify authenticate as that DN instead of using EXTERNAL.